# Запустить скрипт php пониженный приоритет

Tags: shell, php

Есть скрипт php и есть хостинг свебРаньше скрипт выполнялся 20 минут (обновлял прайс) все ОК былощас я оптимизировал скрипт он выполняется 35-45 секНо у свеб что то поменялось и скрипт бывает убивает время от времениМне сказали что нужно либо разбить скрипт на несколько подскриптов мол снизить время выполнения до 10 с - что для меня не приемлимоИли 2 снизить как то нагрузку... мне сказали запускать php как то через cliя понятия не имею как это сделать?!

Подскажите какую можно повесить команду на крон, чтобы запускался скрипт и не жрал много ресурсов?

Comment: запустить в cli означает `php /path/to/script.php`

Comment: можно подробнее что значит cli и может ли это помочь?

Answer (score 1):

20 минут! И php терпел?! Ну неплохо :) Но, если вы оптимизировали и время выполнения стало меньше, то куда ж ещё-то. Для начала проверить бы что указано в php.ini насчёт временного лимита, а ещё попробуйте запустить скрипт с вот такой строчкой вначале "ini_set('display_errors', 1);". Это вам покажет возможно имеющиеся ошибки. set_time_limit попробуйте. Ну и далее, если не поможет, обращайтесь, но только с подробностями (желателен код), а то вдруг у вас там бесконечный цикл в скрипте....

Comment: у меня стоит в начале скрипта:ini_set('max_execution_time', 9600);ini_set('memory_limit', '100M');set_time_limit(9600);ignore_user_abort(true);

Comment: ничего не помогает. там дело в том что сначала было так. файл xml у меня разбирался и обновлялась сразу таблица товаров. мол UPDATE... это реально долго работало. Потом я придумал сразу xml файл загружать во временную таблицу запросами INSERT это в разы увеличило скорость. Дак вот может как то ресурсы проца сильно жрутся когда работает скрипт очень быстро и плотно с MYSQL.

Comment: так как поддержка хостинга мне сказала что мол скрипт загружает проц в перыве 10 сек на 50% потом растет еще за 10 сек до 80% и срабатывает КИЛЛ процес, но самое интересное иногда скрипт хорошо отрабатывает. особенно если поддержка там чето возится с ним.я уже наверно месяц с лишним не могу решить эту проблему с ними. Постоянно пишу в поддержку мол скрипт опять перестал рабоать. Они там чето поделают. скрипт заработает. и поработает для 2-3 потом снова....потому что на локальном все отрабатывает быстро и моментально без ошибок. я умом понимаю дело в каких то лимитах.

Comment: хостинг у меня обычный не ВДС ничего в php.ini поменять не могу

Comment: Ну а как насчёт такой оптимизации: сначала формируете запрос из INSERT-ов, чтобы не один INSERT на один запрос, а сразу много ну и потом собственно отправляете этот запрос к базе mysql_query? или у вас так и сделано?Насчёт php.ini... Не всегда его править обязательно. Можно некоторые параметры прописывать в .htaccess